# Show user location in django admin

Tags: python, django, location

There was a task to implement a map in the admin interface in Django.
I have a model that stores data about users GPS.

```
class Geoposition(BaseModel):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("User"))
    task = models.ForeignKey("Task", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name=_("Task"), null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", verbose_name=_("Longitude"))
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", verbose_name=_("Latitude"))
    battery_level = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", verbose_name=_("Battery Level"))
    speed = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", verbose_name=_("Speed"))
```

Here I refer to the "Task" model by Foreign Key.

In Django admin in Task model I have Inlines

```
class TaskTransitInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Geoposition
```

I need that when you click on Inline inside the Task model, a map displaying the user’s tracking will open
Maybe someone has encountered this problem and can help me

I looked at several libraries, but I have no idea which one might be useful to me

Comment: Look here https://leafletjs.com/ .

Comment: @Pycm thx for reply! Where I need to write js code? In change_form.html or?